# Не подключается слайдер slick

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

Не подключается слайдер

Стили

```
<link  href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
```

Скрипты

```
        <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>       
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
```

[image: l]

Структура такова
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй указывать полную ссылку. Плюс сперва нужно подключать библиотеки и только после свой код. Рекомендую использовать относительный путь для указания пути к чему-либо. Если другие варианты не помогают попробуй использовать cdn. Данный вариант работает:

```js
 $('.your-class').slick()
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css"/>

<div class="your-class">
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вначале надо подключать главные скрипты, а только потом зависимые от них. Как следствие, для начала надо подключить сам *Jquery*, а только потом то, что его использует

Comment: я подключал так, но результат такой же                                                                                                          <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

Comment: Я вам не верю (кэш может быть забыли почистить или сохранить файл)

Comment: кэш чистил и файл точно сохранял, поэтому и прошу помощи, бо не понимаю в чем причина

Comment: Другой причины быть не может.

Comment: Максимум можно скачать jquery и подключить локально т.к. может быть с удалёнки не может....